# How to i dynamically Change the color of Bullet based on condition

Tags: amcharts, amcharts4

I'm developing analytic dashboard using amchart4 to render graph.
But i don't know how to change bullets color based on conditional

```
var series2 = chart.series.push(new am4charts.LineSeries());
series2.dataFields.valueX = "PROJ_LF";
series2.dataFields.categoryY = "Roundtrip_Market";
series2.strokeWidth = 0;

var bullet1 = series2.bullets.push(new am4charts.Bullet());
bullet1.tooltipText = "Value: [bold]{valueX} %[/]";
var image = bullet1.createChild(am4core.Image);
image.href = "assets/images/proj_lf_red.png";
image.width = 7;
image.height = 41;
image.horizontalCenter = "middle";
image.verticalCenter = "middle";
var series3 = chart.series.push(new am4charts.LineSeries());
series3.dataFields.valueX = "LY_FLOWN";
series3.dataFields.categoryY = "Roundtrip_Market";
series3.strokeWidth = 0;

var bullet2 = series3.bullets.push(new am4charts.Bullet());
bullet2 .tooltipText = "Value: [bold]{valueX} %[/]";
var image1 = bullet2.createChild(am4core.Image);
image1.href = "assets/images/ly_flow.png";
image1.width = 7;
image1.height = 41;
image1.horizontalCenter = "middle";
image1.verticalCenter = "middle";
```

[image]
problem is about bullet1 , bullet2
Now, bullet1 color is RED and bullet2 is Black
but, i need dynamic to change color
if bullet1>bullet2 bullet1 color is RED

if bullet2>bullet1 bullet1 color will be green

is there a way i can achieve this result.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

I know this question is 7 month old but i had a similar problem and found a solution.

You can iterate through your data array before assigning it to your chart and add a condition based property that could look like this:

```
config = {
   fill: am4core.color('#ff0000'),
};
```

now you can add the `dataField` property to the part of your chart that sould get another color in my case it was:

```
series.columns.template.configField = 'config';
```

now the chart will consider if your data item has a config property and change any setting that is listed in your config for this specific entry.